# html virtual keyboard issue on Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, keyboard

I have created a mobile web application that has a form with various input fields.  I have two consecutive fields that are both input type=text fields.  By default, the alpha virtual keyboard should be displayed when the focus goes to one of these fields.  Initially if the focus is manually placed onto the first field of input type=text, the alpha virtual keyboard appears.  If the user then manually changes the keyboard to numeric and presses a key on the virtual keyboard to automatically go to the next input type=text field, the browser should once again display the alpha keyboard, respecting the type of the current field.  This does not happen in Android 4.0.4.  It keeps the numeric keyboard displayed and does not set it to alpha even though the field it is on is of input type=text.  This happens in both the standard Android browser and on Chrome.  It works correctly in iOS Safari.  Is there anything that can be done programmatically to correct this behavior?

A similar issue happens if the first field is input type=number and the keyboard is initially numeric.  When using the "TAB" or "NEXT" key on the virtual keyboard to tab to the a input type=text field, the keyboard remains as numeric.  It does not respect that the field the focus has gone to is of type text.  Is this just an obvious oversight on the part of the Android OS?

Comment: I would test it on some other versions of Android - it could be a bug and out of your control. If it's working fine on iOS then it isn't your website...

Comment: It does work fine in iOS.  I am testing with the latest version of Android I can for my device.  I assume it is a bug but I was just wondering if there was some programmatic workaround for it.

Comment: I would test on more devices... it sounds like your webpage is fine.